# convert.php does not run in a screen session

Tags: php, shell, gnu-screen, simple-machines-forum

I am trying to convert a big forum. 
At the moment I have to do this via ssh and start convert.php with "php5 -f convert.php -- $OPTIONS".
But my internet connection is a bit buggy and so it is often killed.

If i start the above working command in a screen session it does not work. Instead php gives me the HTML code of the "convert.php" back.

head of the page:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6bc4370b2d8d40ff8c3ab23672ff4135; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

Does it has something to do with the Sessions? But why does it work on the same ssh-connection without screen?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any convert.php in the standard simple machines forum package. What conversion are you running exactly? Are you sure it is built to be used as a command line script?

**Edit:** you could try `nohup php5 -f convert.php -- $OPTIONS &` if you cannot use screen.

nohup -> don't kill the process after the current session dies

& -> run in the background

Comment: Great!
Thanks for the really fast answer.
I try it as soon as possible.

I am using BurningBoard2 to SMF 1.11 Converter found here:
http://download.simplemachines.org/?converters;software=burningboard

And yes, it has a CLI support.

Thank you